# Shaking algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

Can someone help me with algorith.
Basicaly if I have word Hello,I should take last letter and put in first position,then take penultimate letter and put it after second letter and so on,take third letter and put it in third position.
It should look like that:
Word:Hello
1)oHell
2)oHlel
This is my code which I have by right now.

```
    public static String caesarAlgorithm(
            String word) {
            char[] arr = word.toCharArray();
            int s=arr.length-1;
            for (int i=0; i<arr.length/2; i++) {
                char temp = arr[i]; 
                char temp1=arr[i+1];
                arr[i] = arr[s];
                arr[i+1] = temp;
                s--;
            }
            return new String(arr);
            }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print(caesarAlgorithm("Sokolade"));

    }

}
```

It should outpirnt in my case eSdoaklo
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the result in a new String. That way, you won't have to handle the index shifting on each permutation.

```
public static String caesarAlgorithm(String word) {
    char[] arr = word.toCharArray();
    String result = "";
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length/2; i++) {
        // get the i-th letter from the end and put it in the result string
        result += arr[arr.length-1-i]; // -1 because index starts at 0
        // get the i-th letter from the begining and put it in the result string
        result += arr[i];
    }
    if (arr.length%2 != 0) {
        // in case the number of characters is odd, add the middle character to the end of the string
        result += arr[arr.length%2+1];
    }
    return result;
}
```

Side Note:

The method name is missleading as it is not a ceasar cipher algorithm. With a caesar cipher, you change all of the character values with the same offset, but their index doesn't change.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of problem has a natural recursive structure:

```
static String shake(String str, int n)
{
    if(n == 0) return str;

    String lastChar = str.substring(str.length()-1);
    String firstChar = str.substring(0, 1);
    String middle = str.substring(1, str.length()-1);

    return lastChar + firstChar + shake(middle, n-1);
}
```

Called via the helper function:

```
static String shake(String str)
{
    return shake(str, str.length()/2);
}
```

Test:

```
System.out.println(shake("Hello"));     
System.out.println(shake("Sokolade"));
```

Output:

```
oHlel
eSdoaklo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     public static String caesarAlgorithm(String word) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int len = word.length();
        int mid = len / 2;
        int i = 0, j = len - 1;
        while (i < mid && j > 0) {
            builder.append(word.charAt(j--) + "").append(word.charAt(i++) + "");
        }
        if (len % 2 != 0)
            builder.append(word.charAt(mid));
        return builder.toString();
    }
```

, output

```
oHlel
eSdoaklo
```